# Passing information back and forth between multiple figures in GUIDE GUI, Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, matlab-guide

I have created several figures in Matlab (using GUIDE) which act as a config-GUI for a model. The idea is that changes made in figure F1 should affect what choices can be made in figure F2, F3, .... However, there are 5 figures, all holding different information, and it is possible to navigate arbitrarily between the figures (push buttons on each figure, to every other figure).

A large issue is that I want only one figure to be open at any point in time. That is, when F1 has started F**X**, I want F1 to close. Hence, I think it is unsuitable to use global variables. (?)

My issue is that I am simply not capable of holding all the data up to date. Maybe this could be achieved using appdata or guidata, but I cannot wrap my head around it.

**Examples:**

1. Since the handles of F1 and F2 differs, passing F1.handles to F2 works (F1.handles shows up in varargin{1} in F2), but I cannot concatenate F1.handles with F2.handles. Hence, I have no apt way of sending F1.handles and F2.handles to F3 (or any other figure). (*If this can be achieved in a more simple way, I might be okay with dropping the "arbitrarily navigation feature", but so far I have not been able to make it work.*)
2. Using .mat-files (i.e., write F**X**.handles to a file and load each file in each Figure) seems such bad practice that I haven't even given it a serious go.

So far, I have not found it necessary to change the data in F**N**±*X* from F**N**, hence I guess the .mat-file approach could work, but my latest idea is using Matlab OOP and pass around a class instead of the handles. I found an old post on the topic ([Global (shared) variables in Matlab GUI code behind. Is there better way to do it then using handles structure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595040/global-shared-variables-in-matlab-gui-code-behind-is-there-better-way-to-do-i)) but it links merely to a [File Exchange](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/33816-example-using-a-matlab-class-to-control-a-gui) and I am unable to understand how to make it applicable for my use case.

**Edit 1:** I found this [Using GUIDE with object-oriented MATLAB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2908635/using-guide-with-object-oriented-matlab), and will give it a try, but I am still having a hard time understanding exactly how to use it, since it seems to require using handles anyway.

Comment: Not an answer, just a suggestion for workaround: If no 2 figures `Fx`/`Fy` would be open at the same time, you could place all your figure components in `panel`s, and keep only one figure. When you change the settings page, you just hide the old panel and display the new one.

Comment: Are each of your "F" GUIs separate GUIs or is it multiple instances of the same GUI? You could use the `'tag'` property combined with `findall` to locate the other windows and then use `guidata(hfig)` to get their respective `handles` struct.

Comment: @Hoki: Hm. Haven't heard of this "panel" thing, I'll look into it.

Comment: @Suever: They are separate GUIs.

Answer (score 1):

U can try using global variables to retrieve handles for all the figures created by assigning handles values to a global variable in a structure format. Global variable persists in memory until you close the figures.

Comment: Aah, I forgot to mention that part. When F1 calls F2, F1 closes. Imagine it like a good old "Setup Wizard". I will edit my question.

Comment: That Edit1: example u can try by updating handles using guidata in the closingFcn.

Comment: handles.myobject = figure_handle;
guidata(hObject, handles);